# How to find out who the Global Administrator is for a directory to which I belong

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have checked in every possible area in the classic Azure portal but I can't seem to find the "Global Administrator" for the directory to which I belong.

Is there a way to find this out in the portal?

Comment: In the new portal (portal.azure.com) you can go to Azure Active Directory and see the list of all users. It's pretty manual though as you have to check each user..

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to look up the company administrators in your tenant by making two queries to the AAD or Microsoft Graph API.

The first query will allow you to identify the objectId of the "Company Administrator" role in your tenant.

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/directoryRoles
```

Then you need to find the directoryRole where `"roleTemplateId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"`, and save the `objectId`.

Next you can query the members of that directoryRole using the following:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/directoryRoles/<objectId>/members
```

Try it all out using the Graph Explorer, and it's demo Tenant:

[Query 1](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2FdirectoryRoles%2F)

[Query 2](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2FdirectoryRoles%2Fd796ff02-38cc-4fe6-a33e-beda871a365d%2Fmembers)

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Global Administrators are also called Company Administrators. The following PowerShell script can help you print out all your Company Administrators. The Install-Module is included in case you do not already have the AzureAD PS Module installed.

```
# Install-Module AzureAD


Connect-AzureAD -TenantID [Your Tenant ID]

$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Company Administrator'}
Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId | Get-AzureADUser
```

Comment: The `AzureAD` module is Windows only so may not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way on the portal, however using PowerShell, enter the following code:

`Connect-MsolService #to connect to your Azure tenant
Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId (Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Company Administrator").ObjectId`