# Issue with Microsoft Graph API app registration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a use case to integrate certain Office365 services with my custom application. I am contemplating using Microsoft Graph API for this integration.

I am following the standard OAuth 2.0 for integrating Office 365. Here are the steps:

Create ‘Dev App’ through Microsoft Dev Application Portal.
Assign the required ‘Delegated Permissions’ to the App.
Provide the consent to the App and get the authorization code.

I am getting the following error when I am trying to provide consent to my App;

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Apparently, this requires an admin account for approval.

Can anyone let me know how to process and whom to contact to get approval for this app?

Comment: You may need to contact your tenant's global admin for them to give consent. Look here for suggestions on how to find the global admin - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2018/04/20/how-to-find-the-global-admin-for-your-azure-ad-tenant/  and another SO post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960561/how-to-find-out-who-the-global-administrator-is-for-a-directory-to-which-i-belon

Answer (score 0):

> how to process and whom to contact to get approval for this app?

Yes, you need the Global admin to give you the consent, and you could contact your global admin to make this.

For the process about consent framework, you cloud read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework).